# HBASE 0.94.1 compatibility with hadoop

Tags: hadoop, compatibility, hbase

I am new to HBASE and HADOOP and would require available compatible versions of hbase and hadoop to run my experiments.

The current stable version of at "http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror/hbase/" is hbase-0.94.1 . Can anybody kindly tell which version of hadoop should I use so that there is no
compatibility issue and no future data loss.

Please suggest from the hadoop and hbase releases that are currently available online.

below are the sites I am using for downloading these releases

http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror/hadoop/common/ (hadoop)
http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror/hbase/ (hbase)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure about the compatibility of the `Hadoop` and HBase distribution you are using, you might consider using the `Apache Bigtop` project or the `Cloudera CDH` package.

[BigTop](http://incubator.apache.org/bigtop/) :

> The primary goal of Bigtop is to build a community around the
>   packaging and interoperability testing of Hadoop-related projects.
>   This includes testing at various levels (packaging, platform, runtime,
>   upgrade, etc...) developed by a community with a focus on the system
>   as a whole, rather than individual projects.

[Cloudera](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Downloads) :

> CDH consists of 100% open source Apache Hadoop plus nine other open
>   source projects from the Hadoop ecosystem. CDH is thoroughly tested
>   and certified to integrate with the widest range of operating systems
>   and hardware, databases and data warehouses, and business intelligence
>   and ETL systems.

Answer (score 0):

Download both from stable folder. I do not know if some version is not compatible with other.

Answer (score 0):

i use **hadoop-0.20.203.0** with **hbase-0.94.1** with out any problems.

Comment: I don't know how to contact eith you, I think this is the place from where I can ask my doubts from you. I also stuck in HBASE and HADOOP compatibility issue. Please see given link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122010/why-namenode-is-not-working-in-hadoop-given-setup