# Why Namenode is not working in Hadoop given setup

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I want to establish HBase cluster of 2 nodes. For that I first establish Hadoop setup. It works fine. Namenode, Secondary namenode, datanode, Jobtracker, Tasktracker, all are working, but when I configure for Hbase, Namenode stucks. It does not work now. Can you tell me why this happening?

**My questions**

1. When hadoop is working, and over that when I configure Hbase. It only shows one machine available. But it have to show two machine available, on `http://hdmaster:60010/master-status`.
2. When I stop all the services, then start all , by using commands,  `./start-dfs.sh` , `./start-mapred.sh`.
   Then it shows, namenode is not working. Why ?

I tried a lot, but I didn't understand why this happening. I think there may be a issue of version. Because the 0.94.2 version  of hbase is used by the tutorial, from where I learnt all these.

I followed [link1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFKs592W_Rc) and [link2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--lax6MCs6k).

Please help me. Looking for your kind response.

**Some information**

```
OS = centOS 5.5
Java = java version "1.6.0_23"
Hadoop = 1.0.3
Hbase = hbase-0.94.6.1
```

**xml configuration(hadoop) for master and slave are as follows,**

**core-site.xml**

```
<property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://hdmaster:54310</value>
</property>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>dfs.permission</name>
        <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>/HADOOP/hadoop/hdfs-data-name</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/HADOOP/hadoop/hdfs-data</value>
</property>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>hdmaster:54311</value>
</property>
```

**xml configuration for hbase for master and slave are as follows**

**hbase-site.xml**

```
<property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://hdmaster:54310/user/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>hdmaster,hdslave</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.datadir</name>
        <value>/HADOOP/hadoop/zookeeper</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2222</value>
</property>
```

**EDIT NO. 1**

When I run following commands, sequentially,

```
./start-mapred.sh

./start-dfs.sh

./start-hbase.sh
```

Then, `./start-hbase.sh` ,gives following output

```
[hadoop@jhamb bin]$ ./start-hbase.sh
hdmaster: starting zookeeper, logging to /usr/local/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hadoop-zookeeper-jhamb.adobe.intern.out
hdslave: starting zookeeper, logging to /usr/local/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hadoop-zookeeper-hdslave.out
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin/../logs/hbase-hadoop-master-jhamb.adobe.intern.out
hdmaster: regionserver running as process 9551. Stop it first.
hdslave: regionserver running as process 5850. Stop it first.
```

Comment: what does your logs show??

Comment: @Tariq There is no log in ` /usr/local/hadoop-1.0.3/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-jhamb.adobe.intern.out`.

Comment: @Tariq See Edit no. 1. May be that will help you to solve my problem. Please help me.

Comment: is your hadoop running fine??what do you see at "hdmaster:50070"?

Comment: Yes my hadoop running fine, when I remove all the settings of Hbase. hdmaster:50070` shows about namenode just like, how many nodes are live, etc.

Comment: edit the line "export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK" in your hbase-env.sh file and set it to true. then restart your hbase. for a detailed info you can visit this link : http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-configure-habse-in-pseudo.html#.UXLo9zWH6IQ...although it is for one node setup, the procedure is almost identical for a distributed hbase setup except a few changes. and what does your hbase logs say?

Comment: @Tariq I set export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK  = true. But again it shows the same error. As in edit no 1. `hdmaster: regionserver running as process 9551. Stop it first.
hdslave: regionserver running as process 5850. Stop it first.`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28578/discussion-between-tariq-and-devsda)

Comment: @Tariq Hii, hows you? I stuck in one problem. Please help me, I posted that on SO, see the link , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250531/how-to-implement-http-1-1keep-alive-feature-in-my-web-server . Give me some guidance.